# How to copy each paragraph from .docx file to new row in .csv file?

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I am new to python. I am trying to parse a .docx file and copy each paragraph to an individual row in a new .csv file.

I am able to count the number of paragraphs accurately, as well as print the entire document, but I am receiving errors when trying to iterate through the document to parse each paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you could start by installing the package called "docx" (do 'pip install docx' on your terminal or command line if you have python2 or 'pip install python-docx' for python3).

Then you can run the following code:

```
from docx import Document
import pandas as pd

document = Document('text.docx')
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['paragraph'])
for para in document.paragraphs:
    print(para.text)
    df.loc[len(df)] = para.text
print(df)
```

I hope it helps.
BR

Comment: The `python-docx` package name applies regardless of the Python version and is installed in the latter way you mention, although some might use `pip3 install python-docx` in that case. The `docx` package refers to an obsolete pre-cursor package that has a different API (no Document object being a main difference), so it would fail at the import. Good answer otherwise, I upvoted :)